# search from values of a property on another property in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using Mongodb Driver and c#. I have a collection like below:

```
Post collection:

Post:[
{
 PostId:5,
 CreateByUserId:"james",
 Privacy: "People",
 People: {
  Groups:[1,2],
  Friends:["simon","oliver"]
 },
 GroupMembers:[{UserId:"kevin",GroupId: 1},{UserId:"george", GroupId:1},{UserId:"jack",GroupId: 2}]
}
]
```

I need a search query to retrieve UserIds from `GroupMembers` that are in the `People.Groups`.below is what I want in linq :

```
$GroupMembers.Where(a => People.Groups.Contains(a.GroupId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe what you try to achieve is filtering the data in the projection. Working with LINQ should be fine.

```cs
var result = _col.AsQueryable()
    .Select(x => new Post
    {
        PostId = x.PostId,
        CreateByUserId = x.CreateByUserId,
        Privacy = x.Privacy,
        People = x.People,
        GroupMembers = x.GroupMembers
            .Where(y => x.People.Groups.Contains(y.GroupId))
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Otherwise, you should do it in a `.find()` or `.aggregate()` query with `$filter` operator.

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  GroupMembers: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$GroupMembers",
      cond: {
        $in: [
          "$$this.GroupId",
          "$People.Groups"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OzzOu9BwfSb)